# Return one result per ChatID

Tags: php, sql

I am getting data from a table and ordering them by a column in another table. Below is my query.

```
$query = "SELECT Chatroom.ChatID, Chatroom.User1, Chatroom.User2 FROM `Chatroom` JOIN `Messages` ON Chatroom.ChatID = Messages.ChatID WHERE User1 = ? OR User2 = ? ORDER BY Messages.MessageDate";
```

Say there is a chat between two people and they've messaged 10 times. I will get 10 results when really I want 1 result. I realize it's looping through messages because I joined them on chatID but I do that to get the dates.

Is there a better way to get this or is there any easy adjustment to my query that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, maybe try this?

```
SELECT c.ChatID, c.User1, c.User2
FROM Chatroom AS c
  JOIN (
    SELECT mx.*
    FROM Messages AS mx
    WHERE mx.ChatID = c.ChatID
    ORDER BY mx.MessageDate
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS m ON m.ChatID = c.ChatID
WHERE c.User1 = ?
  OR c.User2 = ?
ORDER BY m.MessageDate;
```

---

Try this instead?

```
SELECT c.ChatID, c.User1, c.User2
FROM Messages AS m
    JOIN Chatroom AS c on c.ChatID = m.ChatID
WHERE (c.User1 = ? OR c.User2 = ?)
GROUP BY c.ChatID
ORDER BY m.MessageDate
```

Comment: This returns a call to member function bind_param() on a non-object error. I'm actually not sure why though because it seems like there is no syntax error's in the sql and im binding ('ii', $userID, $userID)

Comment: @Ryne
```$sql = "
    SELECT c.ChatID, c.User1, c.User2
    FROM Chatroom AS c
      JOIN (
        SELECT mx.*
        FROM Messages AS mx
        WHERE mx.ChatID = c.ChatID
        ORDER BY mx.MessageDate
        LIMIT 1
      ) AS m ON mx.ChatID = c.ChatID
    WHERE c.User1 = :userid
      OR c.User2 = :userid
    ORDER BY m.MessageDate;
    ";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userID);
    $stmt->execute();```

does this work?

Comment: @Ryne sorry, are you using PDO, or how are you connecting to the database?

Comment: Im not using pdo though. I tried it anyways (undefined variable $pdo)..

Comment: so that get's rid of the error..but it limits all results to 1. so if i have two chatrooms for a user I only see 1 result when there should be two. still showing say 5 results if theres 5 messages but only 1 chatroom..hope i explained that right haha

Comment: @Ryne ok try that second version now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161777/discussion-between-e-e-and-ryne).

Comment: yes!! ok it was the group by that did the trick .. forgot about GROUP BY..thank you i really appreciate the help!